# credit card style issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles

I am trying to change the border color of credit card input, yet it is not working

Here is [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-credit-card-input) for creditcardinput. Here is a [demo](https://medipass.github.io/react-credit-card-input/?selectedKind=CreditCardInput&selectedStory=custom%20styling%20%28field%20wrapper%29&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) where green custom border color is applied. Here is hosted on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-star-bnx0s)

```
  <CreditCardInput
    cardNumberInputProps={{  }}
    cardExpiryInputProps={{  }}
    cardCVCInputProps={{  }}
    style={ { border: '2px solid yellow' } }
 />
```

Comment: `style` is not a supported prop.  Maybe `containerStyle` could work.  I suggest you read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `fieldStyle` or `containerStyle` prop instead of the `style` prop. Using either seems to produce the same results at least in the codesandbox example you've shared, though there may be differences between the two as your code changes.

From the [available props documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-credit-card-input#available-props):

> ```
> containerStyle |  object (optional)  |  {}  |  Style for the field container
> fieldStyle     |  object (optional)  |  {}  |  Style for the field
> ```

Example:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CreditCardInput
        cardNumberInputProps={{  }}
        cardExpiryInputProps={{  }}
        cardCVCInputProps={{  }}
        fieldStyle={ { border: '2px solid yellow' } }
/>
```